# JSON on post data attach the string on it

Tags: javascript, json, constants

Hey I am new to JSON and for this project I am using POST using a variable fetch_email inside the customer_porperties. Currently if I send out the value as `{"$email": "sunny@gmail.com"}` , it gets submitted. But if I use `var fetch_email = "sunny@gmail.com"` and call it on `{"$email": fetch_email}`  , it does not submit and throws an error. What's the better way to call the variable inside the `const body data` for JSON ? Can anyone please help on it ?

```
const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {Accept: 'text/html', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: new searchParams({
          data: '{"event": "game mode", "customer_properties": {"$email": fetch_email}}'
        })
      };

      fetch('https://thrid_party/api', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Don't generate JSON by mashing strings together. Use `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manually build JSON strings, use the built-in `JSON.stringify()`.

```
body: new searchParams({
    data: JSON.stringify({"event": "game mode", "customer_properties": {"$email": fetch_email}})
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
data: `{"event": "game mode", "customer_properties": {"$email": ${fetch_email}}}`
```